# Combining two arrays and delimiting every other with symbol (=)

Tags: php, arrays, delimiter

I have two variables with this structure:

```
$columns = "col1, col2, col3";

$values = "$value1, $value2, $value3";
```

What do I need to do to get:

```
$combined = "col1 = $value1, col2 = $value2, col3 = $value3";
```

I am pretty sure i need to:

```
explode(',', $columns);
explode (',', $values);
$combined = array_combine($columns, $values);
$combined = implode(',', $combined);
```

but then i just get:

```
$combined = "col1, $value1, col2, $value2, col3, $value3";
```

How do I replace every other comma with a "="?

Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: that gives col1 = $value1 = col2 = etc...

Comment: and just like that its gone lol.

Comment: lol, sorry I replied too fast and then I realised that I was wrong :)

Comment: Otherwise, what's wrong with using a loop ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV How would i go about that? It would have to be foreach wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$columns = 'col1, col2, col3';
$values = '$value1, $value2, $value3';

$result = implode(
    ', ',
    array_map(
        function ($c, $v) {
            return $c . ' = ' . $v;
        },
        explode(',', $columns),
        explode(',', $values)
    )
);

var_dump($result);
```

But if you want this for building a SQL insert statement, use a MySQLi or PDO prepared statement instead

Comment: Array_map huh? Wow. will give it a go!

Comment: Yeah thats what its for. I want it to INSERT and then change the query UPDATE but its a different structure for UPDATE.

Comment: I'm running on php 5.3 i don't need to adjust anything do i?

Comment: @Mark I get syntax error when executing this in php 5.2.17: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'` any ideas?

Comment: which lands on the function line btw.

Comment: Closures require PHP>=5.3.0 which you should have upgraded to anyway as the 5.2 branch is no longer supported

Answer (score 1):

This should work....

```
$columns = explode(',', $columns);
$values = explode (',', $values); 
$combined = array_combine($columns, $values);
array_walk(&$combined, function(&$v, $k){
    $v = $k."=".$v;
});
$combined = implode(",",$combined);
```